# Modify Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox display settings

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, rendering-engine

I would like to know if it is possible to modify Chrome or Firefox display settings, so that it would only show rectangles of HTML DOM objects? What I want to do is to decrease rendering engine job amount as much as possible, so it would only build layout of the page.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with this? If you say what you are trying to do (why you want to decrease the rendering engine job) then we might be able to help more.

Comment: i want to develop some sort of php+js script, which would dynamically load web page into the frame from some list of links, then it would extract coordinates of HTML DOM objects, store those coordinates, and then repeat all this with another page. I want to work this as fast as possible, that why I want to decrease amount of job for rendering engine.

Answer (score 1):

People usually refer to this mode of operation as "headless" (i.e. without UI).

Usually there's an additional requirement - to be able to run it server-side without the usual for client software installed. If you're running it client-side, I wouldn't bother about optimization, it shouldn't give you a big win anyway.

Otherwise, try searching using that term. I've seen it asked for several times, but haven't seen a working out-of-box solution.

[edit] just saw http://hg.mozilla.org/incubator/offscreen, which seems to be a headless version of Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go as low-level as modifying the renderer. Instead, I suggest you use Firefox's [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) to replace the elements from the page with whatever it is you need. You'll need to know a bit of JavaScript, but it's not that hard.

However, this will only work on client side. If you want to do this on server-side ( so that it will work on any page a user requests through your own ), my guess is you'll need to grab the page's content in a string, and then modify it using a HTML parser.